# Analytics Snippet Wordpress Webstite

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

I have pasted the analytics snippet into file "header.php" of my wordpress website. I see Real-Time reports and the tracking Status is "receiving data". But the tracking code is not collecting data for all the page, in fact with "View Page Source" I have seen that many pages don't have the analytics snippet. What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: First thing, you should look in your template files if all templates actually include the header.php file (either you download them and examine them on your local computer or you go to design/themes/editor to see the source code for your active theme).

Comment: HI Eike Pierstorff, thanks for your answer. I have pasted the snipett into the main theme of the wordpress website and with "View Page Source" I have checked that every page has that theme into the code. Maybe the web designer has created another header.php? I really don't know, maybe I can fix this problem with a plugin, but I didn't want to use a plugin just to paste a snippet into the header

Comment: Can I paste here the link to the website?